# How to use get_template_directory_uri() to load an image that is in a sub-folder of my theme?

Tags: functions, theme-development, images

How do I insert an image that is in a subfolder into my theme directory?

I have the following situation: Into my custom theme directory I have the following folder that contains a `jpg` image: `/assets/img/flexslider/flex-1.jpg`

Now in my `header.php` file, I have something like this:

```
<li>
  <img src="assets/img/flexslider/flex-1.jpg">
  <div class="flex-caption">
    <p class="flex-caption-text">
      <span>Lorem ipsum</span><br>
      <span>sit dolor</span><br>
      <span>adipiscing elitur</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</li>
```

Obviously, when I load the page, the image `flex-1.jpg` is not loaded because there is not the right path (in fact using FireBug I obtain that it try to load the `assets/img/flexslider/flex-1.jpg` image) so I think that I could use the absolute path but this is pretty horrible!

So I am thinking to use the `get_template_directory_uri()` function provided from WordPress to do this and I have tried to change the previous code in this way:

```
<li>
  <img src=<?php get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/img/flexslider/flex-1.jpg' ?>>
  <div class="flex-caption">
    <p class="flex-caption-text">
      <span>Lorem ipsum</span><br>
      <span>sit dolor</span><br>
      <span>adipiscing elitur</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</li>
```

But it is not working and using FireBug I can see that it is loading nothing, in fact in my browser source code I have:

```
<img src="">
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should echo it and also you are closing your php tag improperly. View source the o/p generated to get some idea

```
img<src=<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()."/assets/img/flexslider/flex-1.jpg"?> alt="alternative_name">
```

or you can use [bloginfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo) which is easier to remember and use (You need not echo)

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/flexslider/flex-1.jpg"/>
```

Comment: tnx so much :-)

Comment: Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. More Dynamic Way is in your **functions.php** file add this line

   `add_theme_support( 'custom-logo' );`
2. New to display the image use

```
$custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $custom_logo_id , 'full' );
echo '<img src=$image[0] height="100px" />';
```

[Know more](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Logo)

Comment: Why do you think the OP wants a custom logo, I don't see how got that from the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src='<?= get_template_directory_uri() . "./assets/img/flexslider/flex-1.jpg" ?>' alt="flex">
```

You are change `<?php ?>`to `<?= ?>` or `<?php echo ?>`